# badboy showing empty Url while performing Ui recording Test in localhost Url

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

When I was recording my localhost Url through badboy it showed me some empty url links, What does it exactly means ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywLbx.png)

Comment: for screenshot please click on 'enter image description here'

Answer (score 0):

Export from Badboy cause some malformation in the requests data that needs to be corrected manually. Check number of request recorded by Badboy and request in jmeter.

There is no use or blank request and it should be removed.

From badboy:-

> **Limitations**
>
> There are, unfortunately some limitations to Badboy's JMeter support.
> These limitations exist because the features of JMeter and Badboy do
> not exactly match each other and in some cases it is not possible to
> export items directly.
>
> The following limitations should be noted:
>
> **JScript cannot be exported**. JMeter cannot run JScript because it does
> not have an embedded browser window. JScript items will be ignored in
> the script when you do your export.
>
> **Data sources are not exported.**
> JMeter has its own concept to replace Data Sources. When you export
> your file, all of your variables will be created in JMeter as "User
> Parameters". You can, if you wish, provide a file for JMeter to read
> variable values from. Please read the JMeter help on the "HTTP User
> Parameter Modifier" to see how to do this.
>
> **Increments are not**
> exported. JMeter does not use increments to modify variables. Rather,
> variables are automatically modified by the iteration of a loop and
> the presence of a User Parameter Modifier.
>
> **Navigations are not
> exported.** Navigations also rely on having a browser window present and
> thus cannot be directly supported by JMeter. You can simulate them if
> you wish by using Jmeter features.
>
> **Assertions are exported but may need adjustment.**
> Badboy will attempt to export Assertions to JMeter
> but due to small differences in how JMeter and Badboy handle
> Assertions it is possible that they will not always work the same way.
> Badboy automatically scans for these problems and will alert you with
> a message after export containing details about what may need to be
> adjusted.